# What is the best practice to manage API paths in an angular app?

Tags: angularjs

I was looking for a way to manage the external API paths into a single location. Currently, I am storing them as a constant object.

```
var Resources = function () {

var baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/'
var apiURL = baseURL + 'api/v1/';

return {
  URL: {
    API: apiURL,
    ITEMS: {
      INDEX: apiURL + 'items/'
    },
    CATEGORIES: apiURL + 'categories/',
    AUTHORS: apiURL + 'authors/'
    }
  };

  angular
    .module('testApp')
    .constant('RESOURCES', Resources());
```

However, now I am facing problem adding nested endpoints

eg: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/items/1/lease

Here, the above method fails, as "item_id" cannot be placed in the constant object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting approach. We store this as a constant as well, but use string replacement for path variables. For instance:

```
{
  "getStatusById": "/status/:id"
}
```

Then:

```
var url = endpoints.getStatusById.replace(':id', id)
```

Comment: Thanks, this fits in perfectly.